# Waiting long (few minutes) during boot for cryptsetup for password prompt

Tags: debian, dm-crypt, cryptsetup

I have LVM on the top cryptsetup on my Debian unstable amd64. A week ago after upgrade my initramfs changed and now I have to wait few minutes at the beginning of the boot before `cryptsetup` asked for password to unlock partition.
There might be some problem with generated images as at the beginning there were just some kernels affected. After proper run of `update-initramfs -u -k all` installed kernels are affected.

[Wiki instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/InitramfsDebug) don't help much, as `debug` kernel option takes too long and nothing happen (booting just stops).
I tried to debug it with `single break=mount` kernel options, but nothing found.

I see that in initramfs there is running script `/scripts/init-premount`, which starts `dropbear` (nothing unusual).

I have no idea what changed. Any idea, how I can debug problem? Any module missing?

My config:

```
-- /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.3.0-rc5-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/t61-root ro

-- /etc/crypttab
sda2_crypt UUID=c524108a-b40f-49b4-8223-23e3441a7409 none luks

-- /etc/crypttab
sda2_crypt UUID=c524108a-b40f-49b4-8223-23e3441a7409 none luks

-- /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
/dev/mapper/t61-root /          ext4    relatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1    
UUID=411fe373-ec79-45f7-90f2-e50be400c71d /boot   ext4    defaults  0     2    
tmpfs     /tmp tmpfs     nodev,nosuid,size=512M,mode=1777    0    0    
/dev/mapper/t61-home /home      ext4    defaults,relatime        0       2    
/dev/mapper/t61-swap none       swap    sw              0       0

-- /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
dm-crypt
aes-x86_64
xts
sha256_generic
sha512_generic
```

Comment: I've had a similar problem under Ubuntu after moving partitions around, where the initramfs contained two ways to run cryptsetup and only one of them worked (the other had input redirected to `/dev/null` IIRC). Normally the working one ran but in my case it was disabled. The solution was to fix some configuration file (`/etc/crypttab`?) and regenerate the initramfs. Unfortunately I don't remember the details. I suggest tracing through what the scripts in the initramfs are doing (add `set -x` to some files under `/usr/share/initramfs-tools`. If you figure it out, please let us know!

Comment: @Gilles: good point for `set -x`. I've tried to localize problem with regenerated initramfs with inserted debugging messages, but this is going to be much more effective, thanks :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was in unconfigured network, which was required by `dropbear`.

The actual problem with network was my ISP's dhcp server, which is alive, but not providing network setting for me, so I have to set network manually. In initramfs I had to wait for all tries of dhcp. It was in function `configure_networking()` in `/scripts/functions` (source file for `mkinitramfs` in running system is `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/functions`).

Although `dropbear` [is a great](https://projectgus.com/2013/05/encrypted-rootfs-over-ssh-with-debian-wheezy/) solution [for servers](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/579/Unlocking_a_LUKS_encrypted_root_partition_via_ssh) as my system is laptop, I don't need it. I didn't even bother with configuring it or disabling it (in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf-hooks.d/dropbear`), I just simply removed `dropbear` for `initramfs-tools`:

```
apt-get remove dropbear-initramfs
```